# Kendo UI app.navigate("#:back"); not always navigating back

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

Sometimes, not always

```
app.navigate("#:back");
```

does not make the browser navigate backwards in history and the `kendo.history` array will remain untouched.

Why?

How I check the contents of the array:

```
var num = kendo.history.locations.length;
for (var i = num - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  console.log(kendo.history.locations[i]);
```

Tested kendoui version: 2013.3.1424

Answer (score 1):

I customise backbutton on android like this

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
function onBackKeyDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (kendo.history.locations.length){
        if (kendo.history.locations[kendo.history.locations.length - 2] != ""){
            app.navigate("#"+kendo.history.locations[kendo.history.locations.length - 2]);
        }
    }
}
```

or you can use custom class like this

```
$(document).on('touchstart', '.custom-back', function(e){        
    if (kendo.history.locations.length){
        if (kendo.history.locations[kendo.history.locations.length - 2] != ""){
            app.navigate("#"+kendo.history.locations[kendo.history.locations.length - 2]);
        }
    }
});
```